# Running sql query via automation tests in Visual studio vs SQL server management studio returns different results

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio, sql

I am running some database automation tests in C#.The results of the same sql query are different in  visual studio(executed via automation tests) and SQ Server Management studio(Manually).The difference is mainly with the date-time formats.
Example:
Management studio returns :2020-04-18 18:27:51.5354564 -04:00
Visual studio returns: 4/18/2020 6:27:51 PM -04:00

I don't understand what is causing the issue.
Greatly appreciate any help to resolve this !

Comment: SQL Server management studio and visual studio are converting the dates to strings. I'd guarantee VS is using the US date format while SSMS is using its standard format. If you search for C# date formats you can find a lot of information about how C# displays dates.

Comment: How are you doing it through c# please add the code

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by embedding a CAST(expression as varchar(max)) in my sql query and then run the query via automation test in visual studio.